# Knowing real time an user is in my site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

I have a website, and I have to implement (with PHP and/or JavaScript) an alert message that triggers two minutes after a visitor has entered the site. I've searched, but all solutions I've found are for an unique page. I need the timer counter to start when the user enters my site, no matter through which page. And I need that counter keeps counting while the user navigates my site's pages.

One solution could be using session variables. I can make a script that looks for this variable, if it doesn't exist means that the user is entering the site. Then I set this variable with current time. The script it's in each page, and it will be reading this variable via AJAX each x seconds and I'll know when the user is in my site since two minutes.

I don't know if it's right or not (I've not implemented yet), but I'm not pretty sure if session is the best way. If the user leaves the page but has other navigator windows opened, the session doesn't expire, and if he enters the site again, the counter will not be reset.

So, two questions:

1. Is there a better method to have
   more control on the real entering
   and exiting?
2. If not, is my above
   approach right?

Thanks.

Comment: Your thinking is good, but I would suggest implementing the same idea with cookies in javascript. 1) On first load check if your cookie already exists and if it doesn't, set it to current time (be aware that server and client time are likely to differ, so time everything with one clock). 2) `setTimeout(...)` for 2 minutes the first time (and 2 minutes minus the difference between cookie time and current time when page is reloaded).

Comment: But if I create a cookie, when the user leaves my site and then re-enter, the cookie will remain and I won't be able to know if its entering or not. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can set logic that if the document.referrer is not the site to reset the cookie. Easiest way for that is to check if it contains your domain or not.

Comment: You could trust the cookie expiration (browser does that for you, so no need to care). By default cookie expires when browser is closed, which I suppose is what you want. Alternatively, you could set the expiration time manually to any desired value (30min? 1h? 1 day?)

Comment: And if the user has opened other browser windows or tabs, the cookie expires when he closes my site? If not, then it's the same that using sessions, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
$alert_message = false;

if(!isset($_SESSION['time_entered'])){
    $_SESSION['time_entered'] = time();
}

if($_SESSION['time_entered'] =< time() - 120){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['message_sent'])){
        $alert_message = true;
        $_SESSION['message_sent'] = true;
    }
}
```

And in `<head>`:

```
<?php if($alert_message):?>
<script type="text/javascript">alert("You've been here for at least two minutes.");</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Also make sure that you have `session_start()` at the top of every script.

Comment: Thanks, Karl. That's the implementation of my approach, but I'd like to know if there is a way to actually control entering and exiting, since sessions doesn't (I think).

Comment: There's not. Unless the session is closed by the user, logging out for example.

Comment: I think this would trigger on all pages (if user has opened more then one page simultaneously), so you can't really do this without AJAX.

Comment: And I think that this would trigger the alert only when entering a page. If the 'moment' arrives and the user is viewing a page, he would not see the alert until he goes to another page or refresh current one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need AJAX, you just need to store the time in a session variable, and then include some JavaScript on each page, here is an example:

```
<?php
session_start();

$time = microtime(true);

if (!$_SESSION['foo']) {
    $_SESSION['foo'] = (microtime(true)+120);
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('two minutes have passed');
    }, <?php echo bcsub($_SESSION['foo'], $time)*1000 ?>);
</script>
```

You will need some additional logic so that it does not keep firing after the 120 seconds are up.